# When we need to create complex type using values almost similar to another complex type is it better to use a complexContent or create a complex type?

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

Suppose i have a Complex type of the following format

```
<xsd:complexType name="MyComplexType">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="FirstName" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="LastName" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="Age" type="xsd:int"/>
    <!-- Add more elements here as needed -->
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Now if want another complex type which has the same contents as `MyComplexType` which of the following will be the best appraoch?

1. Using complexContent

```
<xsd:complexType name="CustomComplexType">
  <xsd:complexContent>
    <xsd:extension base="MyComplexType">
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="FirstName" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="LastName" type="xsd:string"/>
        <!-- Add more elements here as needed, excluding Age -->
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:extension>
  </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

2. Using choice

```
<xsd:complexType name="MyComplexType">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:choice>
      <xsd:element name="FirstName" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="LastName" type="xsd:string"/>
      <!-- Add more elements here as needed -->
    </xsd:choice>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

3. Creating new complex type altogether

```
<xsd:complexType name="MySimplifiedComplexType">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="FirstName" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="LastName" type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

For ease and not effecting existing schemas, i went with the 3rd appraoch of creating a new complex type. But wanted to know which one the best approach is?

Note: The existing type cannot be edited for my case here so 2nd option also was ruled out. But still wanted include so as to know if that is the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your types are not related each other from a use case point of view you should use different types to avoid coupling between unrelated entities. It will later save you the effort if they diverge independently.

If they are related you can leverage extension. Take out the common attributes into a base type and extend the other types from this base type.

```
<xsd:complexType name="MyBaseComplexType">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <!-- Common Elements -->
    <xsd:element name="FirstName" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="LastName" type="xsd:string"/>

  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>


<xsd:complexType name="CustomComplexType">
  <xsd:complexContent>
    <xsd:extension base="MyComplexType">
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Age" type="xsd:string"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:extension>
  </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="OtherCustomComplexType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="MyComplexType">
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="SomeOtherAttribute" type="xsd:string"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

The `CustomComplexType` and `OtherCustomComplexType` will now contain `FirstName` and `LastName`